# Same ArrayName in struct with different ID

Tags: c, mplab

I'm wondering if i can create two registers with same name but with different size and different id.
Example i need to create a MenuRegister with 40 elements and another with 10;
I 'm using routines which are same for both registers. Till now i need to recreate my routine cause each register has different name. Can I create two register with same name but different ID?

Example

```
 typedef union
{
  unsigned int Value;
  unsigned char bytes[2];

}NonStaticParameters;
//////////WaterPellet///////////////////
extern volatile NonStaticParameters MenuRegister[40];
extern volatile NonStaticParameters ExtraMenuRegister[10];
```

I'm getting error array dimension redeclared

Here is an routine example

```
void TestRoutine()
{
MenuRegister[1].Value={User has set its Value}
....
....
..
..

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to change your routine to accept the value it operates on as arguments - rather than hard-coding the value it operates on.

Comment: It really dont bother me the way i will do it. I'm just trying to find a way how to not recreate my routine. I will give an example in my my post.Can i succedd that with 2d char arrays?

Comment: I believe recreating your routine to accept a (pointer to a) `NonStaticParameters` argument is the best solution.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Will try to give an example later if time permits.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. In `TestRoutine` your are addessing the variable `MenuRegister`. Suppose you have two variables called `MenuRegister`, as you suggest in your example: when you write `MenuRegister[1].Value={User has set its Value};`in `TestRoutine`, how should the compiler know which one of the two `MenuRegister` is meant? Also you write _"same name but different ID"_, there is no such thing as an _ID_.

Comment: Thats what i'm trying to say. How can i create one routine for both my registers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in comments you probably want this:

```
extern volatile NonStaticParameters MenuRegister_1[40];  // different names here
extern volatile NonStaticParameters MenuRegister_2[10];

void TestRoutine(NonStaticParameters menu[], int size)   // TestRoutine with parameter and size
                             // the size parameter is useful so you know
                             // the number of elements in the register
{
  menu[1].Value={User has set its Value}
  ....
  ....
}

TestRoutine(MenuRegister_1, sizeof(MenuRegister_1) / sizeof(MenuRegister_1[0]));
...
TestRoutine(MenuRegister_2, sizeof(MenuRegister_1) / sizeof(MenuRegister_1[0]));
```